# Is the phrase "the new staff at Tech company" correct?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

[An IELTS helper post](https://ieltssharebox.com/how-to-get-high-score-in-ielts-speaking-band-9.html) says

> I'm currently the new staff **at Tech company** with a specialty in IT

Is that correct? Does it need a article in between "at Tech company"?

> I'm currently the new staff **at a Tech company** with a specialty in IT

Is it because of "the new staff"?

Comment: If the technology company isn't specific, you can say "at a tech company". But if you've a context and it is specific, you can say "at the tech company".

Comment: Yes, you either need "a" or "the", depending on the circumstanced outlined above.

Comment: You've capitalized "Tech", but not "company". If it's a company named "Tech", you don't need an article.  Apart from that, you would usually say "I'm a new staff member", unless you're the only person on staff.